# MySQL optimize count query

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, count

I've got a question about MySQL performance.
These are my tables:

(about 140.000 records)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `intro` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `indexed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=132911 ;
```

(about 400.000 records)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_category` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

RUNNING THIS COUNT QUERY:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(id) as total 
FROM (`article`) 
LEFT JOIN `article_category` ON `article_category`.`article_id` = `article`.`id` 
WHERE `article`.`language_id` = 1 
AND `article_category`.`category_id` = '<catid>'
```

This query takes a lot of resources, so I am wondering how to optimize this query.
After executing it's beeing cached, so after the first run I am fine.

RUNNING THE EXPLAIN FUNCTION:

[image]

AFTER CREATING AN INDEX:

```
ALTER TABLE `article_category` ADD INDEX ( `article_id` , `category_id` ) ;
```

[image]

After adding indexes and changing LEFT JOIN to JOIN the query runs alot faster!
Thanks for these fast replys :)

QUERY I USE NOW (I removed the language_id because it was not that neccesary):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total 
FROM (`article`) 
JOIN `article_category` ON `article_category`.`article_id` = `article`.`id` 
AND `article_category`.`category_id` = '<catid>'
```

I've read something about forcing an index, but I think thats not neccesary anymore because the tables are already indexed, right?

Thanks alot!

Martijn

Comment: Show us the results of EXPLAIN <your query>

Comment: Add an index on `article_category.article_id`.

Comment: Either you shouldn't do a `LEFT JOIN`, or you need to test `category_id = <catid>` in the `ON` clause. Otherwise you'll filter out the articles with no matches in `article_categories`.

Comment: Have you tried creating the other index which I have mentioned... Is this making any difference ?

Comment: Try creating a simple index on language_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created necessary index on the table

Table `article_category` - Create a compound index on `(article_id, category_id)`

Table `article` -Create a compound index on `(id, language_id)`

If this doesn't help post the explain statement.

Answer (score 1):

The columns used in a JOIN condition should have an index, so you need to index `article_id`.